# Trying to add a new user from appsettings.json file to azure storage table

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, azure-storage

I'm getting null reference exception when I run the code.

I created two blocks for reading the user email from appsettings.json and save it with seed method too Azure Storage. It works fine for adding the admin role only. but every time it throws System.ArgumentNullException upon creating the second role.

```
//Works fine
var admin = await userManager.FindByEmailAsync(options.Value.AdminEmail);
if (admin == null)
{
    ApplicationUser user = new ApplicationUser
    {
        UserName = options.Value.AdminName,
        Email = options.Value.AdminEmail,
        EmailConfirmed = true
    };

    IdentityResult result = await userManager.CreateAsync(user, options.Value.AdminPassword);
    await userManager.AddClaimAsync(user, new System.Security.Claims.Claim("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress", options.Value.AdminEmail));
    await userManager.AddClaimAsync(user, new System.Security.Claims.Claim("IsActive", "True"));

    // Add Admin to Admin roles
    if (result.Succeeded)
    {
        await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, Roles.Admin.ToString());
    }
}


//System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null.'
var engineer = await userManager.FindByEmailAsync(options.Value.EngineerEmail);
if (engineer == null)
{
    ApplicationUser user = new ApplicationUser
    {
        UserName = options.Value.EngineerName,
        Email = options.Value.EngineerEmail,
        EmailConfirmed = true,
        LockoutEnabled = false
    };

    IdentityResult result = await userManager.CreateAsync(user, options.Value.EngineerPassword);
    await userManager.AddClaimAsync(user, new System.Security.Claims.Claim("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress", options.Value.EngineerEmail));
    await userManager.AddClaimAsync(user, new System.Security.Claims.Claim("IsActive", "True"));

    // Add Service Engineer to Engineer role
    if (result.Succeeded)
    {
        await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, Roles.Engineer.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question title is not very friendly. [Write a title that summarizes the specific problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please post a code sample in your question and not in your title.

Comment: That's better! Now... can you tell us exactly which line is throwing the error?

Answer (score 0):

> every time it throws NullReferenceException upon creating the second role

> `//System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null.'`

> `var engineer = await userManager.FindByEmailAsync(options.Value.EngineerEmail);`

This code snippet `userManager.FindByEmailAsync(options.Value.EngineerEmail)` will throw the exception if `options.Value.EngineerEmail` is `null`.

*Exception*

[image]

I did a test with following code snippet and json data, which work as expected. Please check if your

*MyConfigOptions class*

```
public class MyConfigOptions
{
    public string AdminEmail { get; set; }
    public string AdminName { get; set; }
    public string AdminPassword { get; set; }

    public string EngineerEmail { get; set; }
    public string EngineerName { get; set; }
    public string EngineerPassword { get; set; }
}
```

*Configuration values in `appsettings.json`*

```
"ConfigOfUsers": {
  "AdminName": "admin",
  "AdminEmail": "admin@example.com",
  "AdminPassword": "Test123456789",
  "EngineerEmail": "user1@example.com",
  "EngineerName": "user1",
  "EngineerPassword": "Test123456789"
}
```

*Bind the MyConfigOptions class to the ConfigOfUsers section*

```
services.AddOptions<MyConfigOptions>()
    .Bind(Configuration.GetSection("ConfigOfUsers"))
    .ValidateDataAnnotations();
```

Test Result

[image]

Besides, you can refer to [this doc about "options pattern in ASP.NET Core"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-3.1) and check if your options pattern related configuration and json data format etc are set correctly.

Comment: I'm using for the configuration class
services.Configure<ApplicationSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings"));

Comment: If you can update your original question to include the code of `ApplicationSettings` class and the testing data you stored in **AppSettings** section, we could reproduce and troubleshoot the issue better.